# Using the sizeof operator with very large objects

Tags: c, sizeof

According to page 135 K&R (as well as [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) wikipedia page), the sizeof operator can be used to compute the size of an object and returns the size in bytes as an unsigned integer of type size_t. Since the max value of an unsigned integer is 2^32, what would happen if I was to call sizeof on an object that had a larger size in bytes than 2^32, like say something with a size of 2^34 bytes. What would sizeof return? And is there a way to get around this size limit?

Comment: Note that the max value of an unsigned integer is not restricted to `2^32`. But you have to ask yourself how such a large object could be used in a system with finite virtual memory address space.

Comment: Does your C compiler support 64-bit compilation, if so, then your `size_t` definition will support greater than 2^32.

Comment: There arn't any valid means to create an object that's larger than a size_t - which easily solves your question. (Though, an "unsigned integer" isn't the same as an "unsigned int". e.g. "unsigned short" and "unsigned long long" are also "unsigned integers")

Comment: @nos The only requirement to `size_t` is being no less than 65535.

Comment: @icepack Why is the only requirement of size_t that it is no less than 65535?

Comment: @user3282276 That's what the spec says

Comment: Note that the maximum value of an unsigned integer depends on architecture and compiler. And even on a typical 32/64-bit architecture, the maximum value is 2^32-1, not 2^32

Comment: Regardless of how much RAM your system can recognize, you cannot declare an object larger than 2^32 bytes in 32-bit architecture, so no problem here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `sizeof` returns the size in bytes as an unsigned integer ***of type `size_t`***

`size_t` is an alias for one of the unsigned integer types (`unsigned int`, `unsigned long long`, `unsigned short`, etc.). Which particular unsigned integer type is implementation-defined.

`size_t` is guaranteed to be able to store the theoretical maximum size of an object on your system. So if your `size_t` is a 32-bit unsigned integer, then it is impossible to create an object bigger than 2^32 bytes on your system. Conversely, if you can create an object bigger than 2^32 bytes, then `size_t` must be bigger than a 32-bit unsigned integer, big enough to be able to store the size of any object you can create.

Comment: "`size_t` is guaranteed to be able to store the theoretical maximum size of an object on your system". Do you have some reference?

Comment: "size_t is an alias for one of the unsigned integer types" -- this is true for C89, afair, but since C99 something like `typedef size_t __size_t` is valid, where `__size_t` could be different from any other integer type.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t and it can be deduced from the fact that `size_t` is the result type of `sizeof`, and `sizeof` is specified to be able to yield the size of any complete non-function type.

Comment: @mafso In that case I would argue that `__size_t` is "one of the unsigned integer types".

Comment: @Oktalist: Agreed. Regarding Grzegorz's point: There are some corner-cases which aren't clear by the standard, I think, like e.g. `size_t huge = SIZE_MAX; size_t too_huge = sizeof(char[2][huge]);`. What is this supposed to do? It cannot give the correct size but must compile (not an overflow in a constant). Otherwise, I agree, if you really have some object, `size_t` can hold its size.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're reading it wrong.

"An unsigned integer" does not mean "the type `unsigned int`". It can also, for instance, be `unsigned long long` which can be (much) larger. Also, of course, there's no requirement or specification that says that `unsigned int` is limited to 32 bits.

Comment: Basically, use of `sizeof` > `unsigned int` is simply `implementation defined`.

Comment: Note that it has to be of type `size_t`, not `unsigned int`. And as such, it's max value is defined by SIZE_MAX macro, which is required to be at least 65535 - this minimal value is rather limited, of course